# How do I get the data in between two Column values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I want to grab the data between column df['Instrument']'s 'Closed Qty' and 'Symbol'. Please refer to the pic. 'Closed Qty' and 'Symbol' both are values of column df['Instrument']. **So, I want to grab all those values in between the row 'Closed Qty' and 'Symbol' and including the row 'Closed Qty' and 'Symbol'.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try following expression:

```
idx = df.index[np.where((df.index >= df[df['Instrument'] == 'Closed Qty'].index[0]) & (df.index <= df[df['Instrument'] == 'Symbol'].index[0]))]
df[df.index == idx]
```

Here `(df.index >= df[df['Instrument'] == 'Closed Qty'].index[0])` finds rows below `Closed Qty` (including it), the expression `(df.index <= df[df['Instrument'] == 'Symbol'].index[0])` finds rows before `Symbol` (including it as well). Numpy `where()` combines both those expressions finding values between `Closed Qty` and `Symbol`.